# When is it better to not use RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

My boss refuses to let me use RelativeLayout. Everything is done using LinearLayout and minimal use of RelativeLayout, such that the layout that I could run with two levels of nesting with RelativeLayout, I now have to do with four using LinearLayout. Any comments on this? What links can share?
In my opinion it would be better to combine these two elements to get the perfect layout.

Comment: Simple answer would be, using Linearlayout you can control look more and make it almost similar even on the device change. And also, using LinearLayout is simpler though starting phase can be quite confusing

Comment: Change your boss not your knowledge :)

Comment: the simple answer is there is no reason about why not to use relative layout. it is depend on the layout designing you require. so you can use combination of many layouts to make a perfect design you desire..

Comment: I normally do the other way: **maximize the use of RelativeLayout, and use LinearLayouts only when I have no other choice (i.e.: to use weights)**!! Your boss needs to learn Android better.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the level of nesting indeed. Android suggests to use a minimum Layouts in Layouts as possible, and if you can achieve with one layout, what you want to do with 3, why not?
The app will run faster for it, though with 2-3 nestings you wont see it.

I for example, create a bunch of included layouts, which i reuse in other layouts.
And the level of nesting could get very deep with that

Answer (score 0):

With the LinearLayout we get the clear separation of view or we can say that each layout is separate. With the Linearlayout each UI element us independent of the other. You get the maximum flexibility. It enables to give the vertical and horizontal orientation.

> Linearlayout you can control look more and make it almost similar even
>   on the device change. And also, using LinearLayout is simpler though
>   starting phase can be quite confusing

From the Docs

> A Layout that arranges its children in a single column or a single
>   row. The direction of the row can be set by calling setOrientation().
>   You can also specify gravity, which specifies the alignment of all the
>   child elements by calling setGravity() or specify that specific
>   children grow to fill up any remaining space in the layout by setting
>   the weight member of LinearLayout.LayoutParams.
>
> LinearLayout is a view group that aligns all children in a single
>   direction, vertically or horizontally. You can specify the layout
>   direction with the android:orientation attribute.

**Again it depends upon your need.**.I also agree with @Lena Bru answer.

Answer (score 0):

## What Is A Relative Layout?

After linear layouts, which display controls in a single row or column, relative layouts are one of the more common types of layouts used by Android user interface designers. Much like other layouts, relative layouts can be defined within XML layout resources or programmatically in the application's Java code. The relative layout works much as its name implies: it organizes controls relative to one another, or to the parent control itself.

Get to love the **`RelativeLayout`**.  It will make your life much easier, when designing for multiple resolutions/densities.  If you have an old SDK, update your eclipse plugin.  It has graphical snap-lines for RelativeLayouts similar to designing a form in Visual Studio, so you can see what is anchored where.  It's really quite good.

[google says:](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/index.html)

*Layouts are a key part of Android applications that directly affect the user experience. If implemented poorly, your layout can lead to a memory hungry application with slow UIs. The Android SDK includes tools to help you identify problems in your layout performance, which when combined the lessons here, you will be able to implement smooth scrolling interfaces with a minimum memory footprint.*